# I tried to set enum field by reflection

Tags: java, kotlin, enums

```
enum class Command(private vararg val commands: String) {

  @FieldEnrich("changeLanguages", "commands")
  CHANGE_LANGUAGE;
}

enum class CreatingCarStep(private vararg val values: String) : AbstractStep<CreatingCarStep> {
  @FieldEnrich("brand-name", "values")
  BRAND_NAME {
    override fun next() = MODEL
    override fun previous() = BRAND_NAME
  };
}
```

I have two enums with vararg property and @FieldEnrich annotation.

Annotation looks like

```
@Target(FIELD, CLASS)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
annotation class FieldEnrich(
  val property: String,
  val field: String
)
```

Annotation is processing by object

```
object FieldEnricher {

  lateinit var configurationProvider: ConfigurationProvider

  fun enrichClass(clazz: Class<*>) {
    clazz.enumConstants.forEach {
      enrichField(it, clazz)
    }
  }

  private fun enrichField(enum: Any, clazz: Class<*>) {
    val enumClass = enum::class.java
    if (enumClass.isAnnotationPresent(FieldEnrich::class.java)) {
      val fieldEnrich = enumClass.getAnnotation(FieldEnrich::class.java)
      val values = configurationProvider.getProperty(fieldEnrich.property, Array<String>::class.java)
      val field = clazz.declaredFields.firstOrNull { it.name == fieldEnrich.field }
      field?.isAccessible = true
      field?.set(enum, values)
    }
  }
}
```

The logic is as follows. We annotate an enum member with the annotation @FieldEnrich and pass the property we would like to read value from and the name of the field to which we set the value of the property.

I was debugging and found out when it was trying to process CreatingCarStep enum is okay, because the enumConstants method returns actual objects of the enum values. So i can just take the class of this value and get the actual class of this enum and process it by my method enrichField. But when it was trying to process Command enum, I got just enum values. So if we take the class of enum value, the same class of Command will be returned. Enter the image description here.

Command image ->
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgwrQ.png)

CreatingCarStep image ->
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sypdt.png)

Comment: This is as expected. Usually, enum values are instances of the same class, similarly as you have for example 20 users and each of them is another instance of the `User` class. Why is it a problem? Each instance of `Command` has its own `commands` field, so it should do what you need. Is there anything in your code that doesn't work as you expected?

Comment: Yeah. Problem that i can't fetch certain class of enum to set field to actual enum instance.

Comment: I think when you start manipulating enums with reflection, you're pretty much asking for all the trouble you get.

Comment: There are no "certain classes" of `Command` enum. There is only a single class, because there is no need to create more of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for `CreatingCarStep` because its enum constants have a non-empty body. This forces the kotlin compiler to create subclasses of the enum class  for each of the enum constants. Additionally, the annotations on the enum constant will be put on the generated subclass. Therefore, `enum::class.java` evaluates to a `Class<*>` instance that represents a subclass of `CreatingCarStep` that has a `FieldEnrich` annotation.

When the enum constants have an empty body, or do not have a body at all, no subclasses are generated. The enum constants are instances of the enum class itself. Hence, `enum::class.java` evaluates to `Command::class.java`, which has no `FieldEnrich` annotation.

Rather than getting `clazz.enumConstants` and getting the annotations on their `::class.java`, you should get the annotations on the enum constant *fields*. This way, you do not depend on whether or not the enum constants have empty bodies.

```
fun enrichClass(clazz: Class<*>) {
    clazz.declaredFields.forEach {
        if (it.isEnumConstant) {
            enrichField(it, clazz)
        }
    }
}

private fun enrichField(enumField: Field, clazz: Class<*>) {
    if (enumField.isAnnotationPresent(FieldEnrich::class.java)) {
        val fieldEnrich = enumField.getAnnotation(FieldEnrich::class.java)
        val values = configurationProvider.getProperty(fieldEnrich.property, Array<String>::class.java)
        val field = clazz.declaredFields.firstOrNull { it.name == fieldEnrich.field }
        field?.isAccessible = true
        field?.set(enumField.get(null), values)
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about field.get(null) -> from documentation ( If the underlying field is a static field, the obj argument is ignored; it may be null.)